# Using expected to handle errors thrown by standard library functions in c++

Tags: c++, exception, functional-programming, c++23

In c++23 we can use `std::expected` to handle errors via a "railroad error handling" approach.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void handleInput(char* argv[]) {
  try {
    std::stoi(argv[1]);
  }
  catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
    std::cerr << "invalid argument " << e.what();
  }
  catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
    std::cerr << "out of range " << e.what();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  handleInput(argv);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to handle the errors that `stoi` might throw via `std::expected` and its method `transform_error` ?

I would expect there to be some way to take the exceptions raised by stoi and pass them to `transform_error` without a try catch block, kind of like how you can access errno after it gets set.

Comment: The standard library does not provide anything to automatically convert exceptions to `std::expected` for you. You have to write the code yourself. If you want to avoid exception, for this particular example (`std::stoi`), take a look at `std::from_chars`. You still need to write the conversion code to `std::expected` yourself even with `std::from_chars`, though.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot do this without try-catch. But you can wrap this try-catch with some wrapper: `auto to_expected(auto callable, auto ...args) -> std::expected<decltype(callable(args...)), std::exception_ptr> { try { return callable(args...); } catch (...) { return std::current_exception(); }`. This code is just an illustration - probably need some polishing

Comment: thanks for the replies everyone, would it be beneficial for us to add wrappers to the syscalls that are provided in c such as select. Also for returning a expected, should we be returning multiple values/stylistic what is expected. for instance lets say we have some error code that occurs in a function, should i return a tuple that has a message and the error code or should i return just the error code or message independently.